# Enabling button on user enter's text Angular 7

Tags: angular

Here I am using reactive forms for data binding.I am facing some problem in disabling and enabling button.

Actually, I am setting some value to the text field initially.

Now I want that update button should be disabled untill user enter something. Its like update a row in a table.

```
  this.firstName= "Angular"
    this.newform = this.fb.group({
        FirstName: [this.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
    });



<form [formGroup]="newform" >
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100%">
               <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                 <input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="FirstName" type="text" required>
        </mat-form-field>
       <button class="btn" (click)= "onSubmit()" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!FirstName" >Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you checking `FirstName`?. Do `[disabled]="!newform?.get('dataSource').value "` instead.

Comment: First: you should set a placeholder not value to the text and you should disable button against the newForm. If newForm is invalid disable button.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a getter in your component

```
get hasFirstName():boolean {    
  return !!this.newform.get('dataSource').value
}
```

and the then on your template, add on the disabled input of your button:

```
[disabled]='!hasFirstName'
```

hope it helps

Comment: No luck.. Can you revisit the code i did couple of changes

Comment: Like @Sachin Jagtap suggested, since you got a validation on your form control, which will control the validity of your whole form, you can enable/disable the button with the validity check

[disabled]='newform.invalid'

Comment: Initially i am binding some value to the input filed on component loads. Even if i set [disabled]='newform.invalid' the button will be enable because it has value inside it.

Comment: Its like update operation which has values already. If user want to update or edit the same text then the button should enable

Comment: Then probably you want to use the `dirty` or `touched` properties, instead of the `invalid`.

Check this https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#why-check-dirty-and-touched

and try `[disabled]='newform.dirty'` or `[disabled]='newform.touched'`